# how can I update vbo data larger than current vbo buffer size?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I generated a vbo buffer (vertex buffer) object called `object_A`,
let's assume that `object_A` contains 10 vertices (30 floats).
Now I want to update `object_A` using `glMapBuffer` with
20 vertices (60 floats), can I use `glMapBuffer`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [`glMapBuffer()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml), that's just for mapping the buffer's data into client address space.

If you want to resize a buffer then you have to use [`glBufferData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml).

```c
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 60 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

If it's because you want something similar to `realloc()` (reallocating the buffer, keeping the old contents). Then you could utilize [`glCopyBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyBufferSubData.xhtml) and copy the data between buffers.